# Call to IdentityServer4 generates System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am intending to get a bearer token via IdentityServer4 via my web project, and I am getting this exception. 
The exception is in the IdentityServer4 open source class library. The field url is null, and this causes the NullReference exception in the AddQueryString method, see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Extensions/StringsExtensions.cs

The log files show;

> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint:Information: ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
>   {
>     "ClientId": "SIR",
>     "ClientName": "SIR",
>     "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:53200/signin-oidc",
>     "AllowedRedirectUris": [
>       "https://localhost:44314",
>       "http://localhost:53200/signin-oidc"
>     ],
>     "SubjectId": "anonymous",
>     "ResponseType": "code id_token",
>     "ResponseMode": "form_post",
>     "GrantType": "hybrid",
>     "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
>     "State": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=WBfqf-a6W0K-0x6giakJP1GCkjUyG0wzOgAr9AuitPNyUb6wsIlzJN-Yvv-ARRdTd5huJIIl3N0mpI95EbLzGKIVmAhXr4JiIWKo2dOCTFI7PH218T9V1vVkKP3kFmQgtRRYRagG9YEA2PvyMtxzQXMf4v3pPequ8Am7H_8TIfgMqspxAnTsXQ4K-cD_TBTVFc45AiDiylpWup1_Ovrpqu700JCGimHZJRuXP25MHMs",
>     "Nonce": "636809130138863279.M2IyNTYyZTgtZTk0Ni00OWU5LWI4MmMtNGU2MWY4M2FkMzQzNzExYjRjYjYtOWY4MC00NjQwLWEyZGYtYzgzYjljZTY4ZDFj",
>     "Raw": {
>       "client_id": "SIR",
>       "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:53200/signin-oidc",
>       "response_mode": "form_post",
>       "response_type": "id_token code",
>       "scope": "openid profile",
>       "state": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=WBfqf-a6W0K-0x6giakJP1GCkjUyG0wzOgAr9AuitPNyUb6wsIlzJN-Yvv-ARRdTd5huJIIl3N0mpI95EbLzGKIVmAhXr4JiIWKo2dOCTFI7PH218T9V1vVkKP3kFmQgtRRYRagG9YEA2PvyMtxzQXMf4v3pPequ8Am7H_8TIfgMqspxAnTsXQ4K-cD_TBTVFc45AiDiylpWup1_Ovrpqu700JCGimHZJRuXP25MHMs",
>       "nonce": "636809130138863279.M2IyNTYyZTgtZTk0Ni00OWU5LWI4MmMtNGU2MWY4M2FkMzQzNzExYjRjYjYtOWY4MC00NjQwLWEyZGYtYzgzYjljZTY4ZDFj",
>       "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET461",
>       "x-client-ver": "5.3.0.0"
>     }
>   }
>   IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in IdentityServer4.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in IdentityServer4.dll
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Critical: Unhandled exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   IdentityServer4.Extensions.StringExtensions.AddQueryString(String url,
>   String query) in
>   C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Extensions\StringsExtensions.cs:line
>   197    at
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.LoginPageResult.ExecuteAsync(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Endpoints\Results\LoginPageResult.cs:line
>   61    at
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService
>   events) in
>   C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line
>   59 IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Critical:
>   Unhandled exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

So in the AddQueryString method, the url is null.
In my web client my startup method is;

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = Settings.SignInAsAuthenticationType    // "Cookies";
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectOptions: new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "oidc",
        Authority = Settings.AuthorityUrl,      //ID Server,  "https://localhost:44314/"; https://localhost:44307/
        ClientId = Settings.ClientId,           // "SIR"
        Scope = Settings.Scope,                 // "openid profile";
        ResponseType = Settings.ResponseType,   // "id_token code";
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = Settings.SignInAsAuthenticationType,
        //--------------------------------------// "Cookies";
        RedirectUri = Settings.RedirectUri,     // URL of website, http://localhost:53200/signin-oidc;
        RequireHttpsMetadata = Settings.RequireHttpsMetadata,
        //--------------------------------------// true
        ClientSecret = "secret"
    });

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        var message = ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            ? $"User: {ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.Name}"
            : "User Not Authenticated";
        await next();
    });
}
```

Notice that I am using Microsoft.Owin

The client in my IdentityServer4 is;

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "SIR",
            ClientName = "SIR",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
            AllowedScopes = new[]
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
            },
            RedirectUris = {
                "https://localhost:44314",
                "http://localhost:53200/signin-oidc"
            },
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256())}
        }
    };
}
```

Why is this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to share the code that is causing this? What line of code is it? Obviously something is `null` and must be given value.

Comment: @Symon -put in doce as requested

Comment: Did you put what line is causing the error? Is it `RedirectUri = Settings.RedirectUri,`? I would recommend checking/stepping through your execution to make sure the `URL` is being passed correctly. If it is `null`, it obviously isn't getting where it needs to go.

Comment: The error is in the IdentityServer4 code, which is an open source library. If you are familiar with the library the error is caused by the url field being null in the AddQueryString method. I want to know why this field is null.

Comment: This is not a duplication question about NullReferenceException. This is a question about how to use the IdentityServer4 open source library which is why I have tagged it in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Add `UserInteraction` to `AddIdentityServer`. It will fix your problem.

```
 services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions()
        {
            LogoutUrl = "/Identity/account/logout",
            LoginUrl = "/Identity/account/login",
            LoginReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl"
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the Identity Server 4 documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html?highlight=UserInteraction#login-workflow), the default login URL is `/account/login`. I believe this error is given if that is not the correct URL for your login. In that case, you can specify the appropriate URL in the `UserInteractionOptions` which can be provided within `AddIdentityServer`.

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions()
    {
        LogoutUrl = "Your/Route/To/Logout",
        LoginUrl = "Your/Route/To/Login",
        LoginReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl"
    };
})
```

These routes should accept a string parameter containing the return URL, the name of which should match the `LoginReturnUrlParameter` property in the `UserInteractionOptions`.